# Can I change a vscode IDE in "GitHub Desktop" to eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, github, ide, github-desktop

[Here is Github Desktop where is IDE to open project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCQwR.png)

[It does't show eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vOdq.png)

How can I change it to eclipse IDE

Comment: Did you know that you can simply drag and drop a GitHub web site onto Eclipse to clone the repository? Support for GitHub pull requests is also built-in (copy PR URL and use _Fetch GitHub Pull Request_ command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github desktop does not support Eclipse. They support 18 IDEs other than VS code on windows. You can view the list with links to each IDE in the [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/installing-and-configuring-github-desktop/configuring-and-customizing-github-desktop/configuring-a-default-editor). You are able to edit the clone in Eclipse then the changes will show up in GH destop. The only difference is that there is no button to open the IDE directly in GH desktop.